# Is there a text file in Google Chrome's app directory containing browser protocols?

Tags: google-chrome, protocols

I recently had to start using Chrome in a medium-to-high security environment, and I've notice that the stricter usage settings create a lot of unexpected dependency issues in regards to plug-in access, protocol execution, etc. I'm  trying to set Google Chrome as my default browser for the MAILTO protocol but am unable to access the protocols list through the settings GUI. Does anyone know if Chrome's  application directory contains a file where the protocols are stored so I can edit/manage the protocols via Notepad? I couldn't find any documentation through Google that suggested this file even existed.

So nobody wastes time suggesting answers I've already tried, so far I have:

- Set Chrome as the default app for the MAILTO protocol in the Windows 7 Control Panel GUI
- Added a javascript handler function to the Gmail javascript console: `navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto","https://mail.google.com/mail/extsrc=mailto&url=%s","Gmail");`
- Observed that the list of protocol handlers in Chrome's content settings GUI shows up blank and un-editable (see screenshot).

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered that this text file actually lives in the AppData file. I went to `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\` and opened the `Local_State` file in Notepad. Protocol settings are listed in the `protocol_handlers` section. I changed the protocol handler authorization for`"mailto":` and a couple others from `true` to `false`, which means they are now authorized for Chrome.